What does the MACNAT flag in a bridge interface member mean?
On macOS 15.1, when a VM configured to use bridged networking is running, I have the following bridge interface, where en0 is the Wi-Fi interface and vmenet0 is a VM's interface:
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether ca:89:f3:ea:e0:64
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vmenet0 flags=10003<LEARNING,DISCOVER,CSUM>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 23 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en0 flags=8003<LEARNING,DISCOVER,MACNAT>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 15 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active

I would like to understand what the MACNAT flag does in this context.
Questions:

What is en0's MACNAT flag?
How does it differ from a bridge setup without member with this flags?
How to remove the flag from the member?


What version of macOS is this? Any details available on your networking setup?

@bmike macOS 15.1, en0 is the WiFi interface and vmnet is vm's interface

What is the actual problem to be solved here? In what way is the interface not behaving as you expect?

Bridging a virtual network interface allows it to connect to an outside network through a physical interface, such as Ethernet or Wi-Fi, making it appear as a normal host to the rest of the network.
What is en0's MACNAT flag?
The MACNAT flag sets the MAC address of the bridge interface to en0's MAC address.
That is, all packets sent through the bridged interface use your Wi-Fi interface's MAC address, which effectively hides vmenet0's MAC address from the network.
MACNAT is similar to Network Address Translation (NAT), but instead of mapping an IP address, it maps a MAC address.
To understand why this is necessary, see the next paragraph.
How does it differ from a bridge setup without member with this flags?
The difference is that, when the flag is not set, members of a bridge interface use their own MAC addresses when sending packets.
This is convenient when combining Ethernet ports into a virtual port, since both interfaces are reachable with ARP requests.
However, as exolained here in detail, it won't work when using a bridge that combines Wi-Fi and a virtual interface because the VM will send packets with its own MAC address, but the router won't know where to send the reply packets because the MAC address of your Wi-Fi interface in macOS will be different,
Luckily, the kernel sets the flag automatically when the Wi-Fi interface is added to the bridge interface:
if (wifi_infra) {
    (void)bridge_mac_nat_enable(sc, bif);
}

How to remove the flag from the member?
You can remove the flag with this command:
sudo ifconfig bridge100 -macnat en0

To add the flag, use this command:
sudo ifconfig bridge100 macnat en0


Thanks for the great answer, just a followup question, is it a requirement just for wireless bridge members? If so, why can wired(ethernet) members work without it?

You're welcome. :-) That's a good question and unfortunately I can't give you a conclusive answer, but I think it has to do with the fact that Ethernet network interfaces can read all packets on the wire and can pick those that have a MAC address of interest, while Wi-Fi works in a different way.
